# Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect (https://cognitiveservices.azure.com), or have expired

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have a chatbot using C# language using Bot Framework and I'm using the Luis api to recognize intent from the user input but I'm getting an error says: Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect (https://cognitiveservices.azure.com), or have expired

```
        var GetRequest = new HttpClient();
        var url = "?q=cars";
        var MSG = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        MSG.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key", "");
        var GetResult = GetRequest.SendAsync(MSG);
        var res = GetResult.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(res);
```

In the url I'm putting the url to call the API and I'm adding the primary key to the headers.

When I test the API on postman its working perfectly and I get the response but in the code i got the error message.

Here is the response that I get when I test it in postman

```
"query": "cars",
"topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Cars",
    "score": 0.90734994
},
"entities": []
```

Comment: First of all, are you using "Luis" or "Langauge Understanding" ( under language studio )? Because OCP Apim subscription key I have seen under only in language studio API, normal Luis is always using get method with prediction key. One more suggestion is instead of creating an HTTP client call you can use the Luis recognizer API part of the bot builder SDK.

Answer (score 1):

"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key" is not the authorisation key, it's a simple header.  There should probably be a BEARER token that you get from a login sequence.

```
MSG.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key", "<your subscription key>");
MSG.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BEARER", "<your bearer token>");
```

Comment: I want to use the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-key header so how can you do it ?